# how to check sequence in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have some scenarios and i need check check sequence for that , i need sequence for following values

This is the actual data which is presented in sql db

- 10001  10001
- 10002  10002
- 10003  10003
- 10005  10005
- 10006  10006
- 10008  10008
- 10009  10009
- 10010  10010

so i need a range for above values like this

- 10001  10003
- 10005  10006
- 10008  10010

and if i am adding new row in sql

- 10004  10004

after insert above row, actual data which is presented in sql db

- 10001  10001
- 10002  10002
- 10003  10003
- 10004  10004
- 10005  10005
- 10006  10006
- 10008  10008
- 10009  10009
- 10010  10010

then the range will be

- 10001  10006
- 10008  10010

and if i am adding new row in sql

- 10007  10007

after insert above row, actual data which is presented in sql db

- 10001  10001
- 10002  10002
- 10003  10003
- 10004  10004
- 10005  10005
- 10006  10006
- 10008  10008
- 10007  10007
- 10009  10009
- 10010  10010

then the range will be

- 10001  10010

can anyone please help to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic gaps and islands problem.  I was able to immediately recognize what your query would require, but as these sorts of problems seem to appear fairly infrequently on Stack Overflow, I needed a reference to jolt my memory.  There is a [great article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175780(v=sql.80).aspx) on Microsoft's TechNet site which goes into depth on gaps and islands and performance.  I recommend that you read it so you can understand how the query below is working.

```
SELECT t1.gapID as startOfGroup, MIN(t2.gapID) AS endOfGroup
FROM
(
    SELECT gapID
    FROM gaps tbl1 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM gaps tbl2 
        WHERE tbl1.gapID = tbl2.gapID + 1
    )
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT gapID
    FROM gaps tbl1 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM gaps tbl2 
        WHERE tbl2.gapID = tbl1.gapID + 1
    )
) t2
    ON t1.gapID <= t2.gapID
GROUP BY t1.gapID
```

I created a Fiddle for your problem in MySQL, because SQL Server seems to be perpetually busted on that site.

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 1):

With any newer version of SQL Server, this can be easily solved using window functions:

```
declare @t table(i int)
insert @t values (10001), (10002), (10003), (10005), (10006), (10008), (10009), (10010)

;with x as (
  select *, case when i = lag(i) over(order by i)+1 then 0 else 1 end g from @t
),
y as (
  select i, sum(g) over(order by i) sg from x
)
select min(i), max(i) from y group by sg
```